# MySQL query with multiple joins but only join one table at a time

Tags: mysql

Now I have 3 tables, `user`, `question` and `answer`. And want to query the user's question and answer in one query. I have tried left join but the result was not what I expected. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT user.id, question.id as question, answer.id as answer
FROM user
LEFT JOIN question ON user.id = question.user_id
LEFT JOIN answer ON user.id = answer.user_id
where user.id = 1;
```

And the result comes out like this:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| id   | question | answer |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 99       | 10     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 99       | 11     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 99       | 12     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 100      | 10     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 100      | 11     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 100      | 12     |
+------+----------+--------+
```

It would greatly affect the performance if user has lots of questions and answers.
What I expect is like this:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| id   | question | answer |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 99       | NULL   |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | 100      | NULL   |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | NULL     | 10     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | NULL     | 11     |
+------+----------+--------+
| 1    | NULL     | 12     |
+------+----------+--------+
```

Which means `user 1` has 2 questions and 3 answers.
How can I get this result in one query? Or need to seperate with 2 queries, one join with `question` and one join with `answer`?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Doesn't an "answer" apply to a particular "question"??  I would expect to see some kind of joining between those tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just union the result of those 2 tables

```
SELECT q.user_id as id, q.id AS question, NULL AS answer FROM question q WHERE q.user_id = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT a.user_id, NULL, a.id FROM answer a WHERE a.user_id = 1
```

Comment: it is a great answer. but what if I want not only the ```id``` of the questions and answers, but also all the columns of both tables? As the number of column is not the same so union won't work in this case. How can I get all the questions and answers of user in one query? Or need to seperate in this case? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```html
SELECT user.id, question.id as question, answer.id as answer
FROM user
FULL OUTER JOIN question ON user.id = question.user_id
FULL OUTER JOIN answer ON user.id = answer.user_id
where user.id = 1;
```

I think what you require is a full outer join.

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL OUTR JOINs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).